# Iterating over an XML response IN C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML response structured as follow:

```
 <e:Parents>
  <d1p1:Parent>
    <d1p1:Name>A</d1p1:Name>
    <d1p1:Child>a1</d1p1:Child>
    <d1p1:Id>101</d1p1:Id>
  </d1p1:Parent>
  <d1p1:Parent>
    <d1p1:Name>A</d1p1:Name>
    <d1p1:Child>a2</d1p1:Child>
    <d1p1:Id>102</d1p1:Id>
   </d1p1:Parent>
   <d1p1:Parent>
    <d1p1:Name>B</d1p1:Name>
    <d1p1:Child>b1</d1p1:Child>
    <d1p1:Id>201</d1p1:Id>
  </d1p1:Parent>
  <d1p1:Parent>
    <d1p1:Name>B</d1p1:Name>
    <d1p1:Child>b2</d1p1:Child>
    <d1p1:Id>202</d1p1:Id>
   </d1p1:Parent>
 </e:Parents>
```

Now based on the given input (e.g. A a2) I need to fetch the id (e.g. 102).

In my function I am trying to use something as such

```
int getId(string str)                         // str = A a2
{
    int index = str.IndexOf(' ');
    string p = str.Substring(0, index);      //A
    string c = str.Substring(index);        //a2
    var parent = response.Parents.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == p && e.Child == c);
    return parent.Id;
}
```

It gives me an error which says:

"The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerables.FirstOrDefault(System.Collections.Generics.IEnumerable,System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying arguments explicitly."

I need to know how can I get the Id based on Parent and Child.

Comment: have you looked at `XPath`?

Comment: No, I have not tried that yet.

Answer (score 1):

The following Linq expression should give you the value you are looking for:

```
XElement xmlSet = XElement.Parse (yourXmlStringHere);

// Will contain the <parent>..</parent> you want
var parentNode =
       xmlSet.Elements("d1p1:Parent")
             .First(e => e.Elements("d1p1:Name").First().Value == "B"
                      && e.Elements("d1p1:Child").First().Value == "a2");

// This will fetch the value - 102 in this case:
var value = parentNode.Elements("d1p1:Id").First().Value;
```

Comment: There could be multiple parent nodes with their Child value as a2.
E.g. Parent A and B both can have a child named a2.
But if the input is 'B a2' I need its Id to be returned. Meaning to say I need to check both values Parent and a Child.

Comment: And I have an XML response. Not an XML string.

Comment: I've updated my answer to check for both `Name` and `Child`. As for your response, you might be able to run linq queries against it (?). If not, I'm sure you can figure out a way to extract the xml as a string, which can be parsed as I've shown here. If you don't need that, then just ignore it. The query is the main point here.